# C++ OOP: how to create a random number generator object?

Tags: python, c++, oop

So this question is sort of one of translation.  I am new to C++, and was looking through the class documentation.  However, it looks like finding the answer to my question is a bit hard via the documentation.

I have code for generating a random number between 0 and 1 in C++: (obtained from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution), since the rand() function solution for floats is integer based)

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1); //corrected from 1,2
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Next, I would like to create a class or struct or something (not really an OOP guy) that has an API like:

```
float x = my_RandomNumberGenerator.next();
```

In python, I might write something like:

```
class my_RNG():
    def __init__(self):
        self.rd = (the random device object I initialize in c code)
        self.gen = (the mersenne_twister engine object)(rd)
        self.distribution = (the uniform real distribution object)

    def next():
        return self.distribution(self.gen)

my_randomNumberGenerator = my_RNG()
print(my_randomNumberGenerator.next())
```

How would I implement this in C++?

**update** Here is what I have so far (it does not work... or compile...but there seems to be some strangeness in the way things are initialized in my template code that I got from the reference site that I don't understand):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>


class MyRNG
{
    public:
        float next(void);
    private:
        std::random_device randomDevice;
        std::mt19937_64 randomGenerator;
        std::uniform_real_distribution distribution;
        MyRNG(float range_lower,float range_upper);

};
MyRNG::MyRNG(float range_lower, float range_upper)
{
    randomGenerator = std::mersenne_twister_engine(randomDevice);
    distribution = std::uniform_real_distribution<> distribution(range_lower,range_upper);
}
MyRNG::next(void)
{
    return distribution(randomGenerator);
}

int main() {
    MyRNG my_rng = MyRNG(0,1);
    std::cout << my_rng.next() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Donald Knuth tells you how.  A better idea would be to find a proven library that already does it for you.  Or maybe the rand() function that's built in: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: oh, the rand() function is an integer function..so it has granularity of the integer range...  I was going off of this for the actual random number generation: 

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution

Comment: @duffymo Please, please don't recommend `rand`. It has *so many* problems. Forget it exists, please.

Comment: @duffymo please, no downvote hate if you are wrong. Just the class structure; honestly.

Comment: Do you need a class like [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/default_random_engine/)? Or maybe you do you want to know how to implement a pseudo-random algorithm, [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). Please, be more clear!

Comment: Your C++ code already fulfils all the requirements*, so it’s completely unclear what you want. (* Well, the function isn’t called `next` but rather `operator()` but that’s in fact *superior* to calling it `next`.)

Comment: Your `python` pseudocode is exactly what you want but with `C++` syntax. I suggest looking up a tutorial that explains `C++` `class` syntax.

Comment: @KonradRudolph So you are saying I'm close?  The code I posted does not work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you just need some form of probability generation class, see below for a basic implementation which meets your question requirements:

```
template<class Ty = double,
    class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Ty>::value>
> class random_probability_generator {
public:
    // default constructor uses single random_device for seeding
    random_probability_generator() 
        : mt_eng{std::random_device{}()}, prob_dist(0.0, 1.0) {}
    // ... other constructors with custom seeds if necessary
    Ty next() { return prob_dist(mt_eng); } 
    // ... other methods if necessary
private:
    std::mt19937 mt_eng;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<Ty> prob_dist;
};
```

Then you can use this simply via:

```
random_probability_generator<> pgen;
double p = pgen.next(); // double in range [0.0, 1.0]
```

Or if you want random `float`s instead (as part of your question seems to imply):

```
random_probability_generator<float> pgen;
float p = pgen.next(); // float in range [0.0f, 1.0f]
```

---

Also, to address why the class you posted isn't compiling, the error in your class is that you try to initialise a `std::mt19937_64` type object (`randomGenerator`) with a `std::mersenne_twister_engine` instance but they are fundamentally different types. Instead you would need to do

```
randomGenerator = std::mt19937_64(randomDevice());
```

in `MyRNG` constructor, or construct via initialisation list as I have done in the example above.

---

As pointed out in the comments, a more suitable *c++-esque* implementation of this is to overload `operator()` instead of creating a `next()` method. See below for a better implementation of the above class,

```
template<class FloatType = double,
    class Generator = std::mt19937,
    class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<FloatType>::value>
> class uniform_random_probability_generator {
public:
    typedef FloatType result_type;
    typedef Generator generator_type;
    typedef std::uniform_real_distribution<FloatType> distribution_type;
    // default constructor
    explicit uniform_random_probability_generator(Generator&& _eng 
        = Generator{std::random_device{}()}) : eng(std::move(_eng)), dist() {}
    // construct from existing pre-defined engine
    explicit uniform_random_probability_generator(const Generator& _eng)
        : eng(_eng), dist() {}
    // generate next random value in distribution (equivalent to next() in above code)
    result_type operator()() { return dist(eng); }
    // will always yield 0.0 for this class type
    constexpr result_type min() const { return dist.min(); }
    // will always yield 1.0 for this class type
    constexpr result_type max() const { return dist.max(); }
    // resets internal state such that next call to operator() 
    // does not rely on previous call
    void reset_distribution_state() { dist.reset(); }
private:
    generator_type eng;
    distribution_type dist;
};
```

Then you can use this similarly to the first class in this answer,

```
uniform_random_probability_generator<> urpg;
double next_prob = urpg();
```

Additionally, `uniform_random_probability_generator` can use a different `Generator` type as a template parameter so long as this type meets the requirements of [`UniformRandomBitGenerator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UniformRandomBitGenerator). For example, if for any reason you needed to use `std::knuth_b` instead of `std::mt19937` then you can do so as follows:

```
uniform_random_probability_generator<double, std::knuth_b> urpg_kb;
double next_prob = urpg_kb();
```

Comment: wow, ok, yeah this is exactly what I am trying to do.  I just have no understanding of what you are doing with the template, then class; the mt_eng, etc. 

But yeah, I think I can accept...thank you

Comment: @bordeo If you only need a single type for your random numbers here, i.e. `float` or `double`, then the template stuff is not necessary and you can omit it - I just left it in so that you can generate both `float` and `double` random probabilities with this class.

Comment: I think I see how it works.  Guess there is a default constructor.  Ok, I need to do some tutorials.  Thank you.

Comment: Your code should **not** provide a `next` function. It breaks all C++ conventions. Just provide an `operator()`, same as the built-in C++ random number generators and random devices (cc @bordeo).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Of course providing an `operator()` is the typical C++ way to do it, I just provided a `next` method simply because the OP used that convention in the question. Also to say providing a `next` function "breaks all C++ conventions" is going a little far imo...

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury Right. The class simply is no longer a generator, which is problematic given that there's no reason to break this concept interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class that holds a random number generator as a private member variable (like `std::mt19937`) and seeds it in the constructor. Your `next` function could just invoke the stored generator to get the next value (applying whatever distribution you want (if any) of course).

This is not very complicated, so I'm afraid I'm missing the *real* point of your question..

Comment: @bordeo, [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134664/generate-random-binary-arrays/134678#134678) on Code Review vaguely attempts to do what you need. I believe you can wonder around there and find some pieces that you need.